# How do I run a python script or compiled python application on a specific port?

Tags: python, linux, networking, server, port

I'm working on a messaging app and I need to run my python application on a specific port.
I need to be able to connect to the application directly on the server's IP and said port using PuTTY.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 Server

I tried connecting to a screen session running the application via SSH but there was no information on how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a server, you can simply bind server to specific IP addr and port and connect using PuTTY.

Bind the IP addr `0.0.0.0` and port `8080`. Connect to server using PuTTY by specific port and ip. `process_data` is where you add your code to handle incoming data and send response to client.

```
import socket

def start_server():
    # Create a TCP socket
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to a specific IP address and port
    server.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))

    # Listen for incoming connections
    server.listen(1)

    # Accept incoming connections
    conn, addr = server.accept()

    print('Connected by', addr)

    # Handle the incoming connection
    while True:
        # Receive data from the client
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        # If no data was received, the connection was closed
        if not data:
            break

        # Process the data and send a response back to the client
        response = process_data(data)
        conn.send(response)

    # Close the connection
    conn.close()

def process_data(data):
    # Add your code here to process the data received from the client
    # ...

    # Return the response to be sent back to the client
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

Comment: the issue is I need to connect to it via PuTTY not using http

Comment: I've updated the code to TCP socket instead of HTTP, as you asked

Comment: thanks, this is closer but still wouldnt work for what my application needs, i have the server code but I need to be able to connect to it and use it as it is via putty

Comment: See the updated code, I didn't know you already had your server code, this should be more straightforward now. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the confusion, let me try reiterate. For example. I need to be able to connect to port 8080 using PuTTY, and have the python script already running on that port so when I login, I can use it as is. This is a helpful solution however it would require me having another application connecting and sending packets via a socket. the client is a placeholder in this, its simply to do with the server. I just need the servers application and code to be accessable by a simple putty login.